# Mapping JavaScript Object property with another property in same JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JavaScript Object and I'm looking forward to `map()` it's `Id` with another `id` in the same JavaScript Object, my JavaScript Object Schema is

```
var items = [
  {
    BossId: "03",
    DateOfBirth: "1966-09-27T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Montejano",
    Gender: "Unspecified",
    GivenName: "Trinh",
    Id: "08",
    Title: "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    BossId: "00",
    DateOfBirth: "1927-01-29T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Fetzer",
    Gender: "Unspecified",
    GivenName: "Winfred",
    Id: "00",
    Title: "CEO"
  },
  {
    BossId: "01",
    DateOfBirth: "1927-08-20T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Dandrea",
    Gender: "Male",
    GivenName: "Erich",
    Id: "02",
    Title: "VP of Marketing"
  },
  {
    BossId: "01",
    DateOfBirth: "1929-02-07T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Nisbet",
    Gender: "Male",
    GivenName: "Reinaldo",
    Id: "03",
    Title: "VP of Technology"
  },
  {
    BossId: "01",
    DateOfBirth: "1932-06-13T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Bufford",
    Gender: "Unspecified",
    GivenName: "Alleen",
    Id: "04",
    Title: "VP of HR"
  },
  {
    BossId: "02",
    DateOfBirth: "1936-09-26T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Klopfer",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Kristyn",
    Id: "05",
    Title: "Director of Marketing"
  },
  {
    BossId: "01",
    DateOfBirth: "1937-11-23T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Duhon",
    Gender: "Male",
    GivenName: "Sophie",
    Id: "01",
    Title: "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    BossId: "03",
    DateOfBirth: "1948-04-05T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Mirabal",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Suanne",
    Id: "07",
    Title: "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    BossId: "04",
    DateOfBirth: "1966-10-13T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Maslowski",
    Gender: "Unspecified",
    GivenName: "Norah",
    Id: "09",
    Title: "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    BossId: "06",
    DateOfBirth: "1967-08-25T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Redford",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Gertrudis",
    Id: "10",
    Title: "Tech Lead"
  },
  {
    BossId: "06",
    DateOfBirth: "1968-12-26T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Tobey",
    Gender: "Male",
    GivenName: "Donovan",
    Id: "11",
    Title: "Tech Lead"
  },
  {
    BossId: "09",
    DateOfBirth: "1969-10-16T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Vermeulen",
    Gender: "Male",
    GivenName: "Rich",
    Id: "12",
    Title: "Trainer Lead"
  },
  {
    BossId: "09",
    DateOfBirth: "1972-10-16T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Knupp",
    Gender: "Male",
    GivenName: "Santo",
    Id: "13",
    Title: "HR Manager"
  },
  {
    BossId: "12",
    DateOfBirth: "1974-03-23T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Grooms",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Jazmin",
    Id: "14",
    Title: "Trainer"
  },
  {
    BossId: "13",
    DateOfBirth: "1978-08-25T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Cheeks",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Annelle",
    Id: "15",
    Title: "Recruiter"
  },
  {
    BossId: "15",
    DateOfBirth: "1979-08-21T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Harshaw",
    Gender: "Unspecified",
    GivenName: "Eliza",
    Id: "16",
    Title: "Trainer"
  },
  {
    BossId: "08",
    DateOfBirth: "1980-02-09T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Broaddus",
    Gender: "Unspecified",
    GivenName: "Xiomara",
    Id: "17",
    Title: "Senior Software Developer"
  },
  {
    BossId: "11",
    DateOfBirth: "1981-09-08T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Jungers",
    Gender: "Unspecified",
    GivenName: "Erminia",
    Id: "18",
    Title: "Software Developer"
  },
  {
    BossId: "10",
    DateOfBirth: "1984-03-18T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Moffatt",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Maria",
    Id: "19",
    Title: "Software Developer"
  },
  {
    BossId: "10",
    DateOfBirth: "1990-09-24T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Grimaldo",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Tammera",
    Id: "20",
    Title: "Senior Software Developer"
  },
  {
    BossId: "10",
    DateOfBirth: "1992-06-18T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Das",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Sharyl",
    Id: "21",
    Title: "Software Developer"
  },
  {
    BossId: "08",
    DateOfBirth: "1993-11-15T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Harlan",
    Gender: "Unspecified",
    GivenName: "Shan",
    Id: "22",
    Title: "UI Developer"
  },
  {
    BossId: "11",
    DateOfBirth: "1997-03-23T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Almeida",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Mariah",
    Id: "23",
    Title: "QA Tester"
  },
  {
    BossId: "11",
    DateOfBirth: "1998-11-10T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Kerfien",
    Gender: "Male",
    GivenName: "Darnell",
    Id: "24",
    Title: "QA Tester"
  },
  {
    BossId: "11",
    DateOfBirth: "2004-04-22T00:00:00",
    FamilyName: "Vierra",
    Gender: "Female",
    GivenName: "Janell",
    Id: "25",
    Title: "QA Tester"
  }
];
```

I'd like to create a function that when provided with a `BossId` will output a list of employees who report to that boss. For example, the output for `BossId` `'03'` would be

```
[
  {
    "BossId": "03",
    "DateOfBirth": "1966-09-27T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Montejano",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Trinh",
    "Id": "08",
    "Title": "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "03",
    "DateOfBirth": "1948-04-05T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Mirabal",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Suanne",
    "Id": "07",
    "Title": "Tech Manager"
  }
]
```

What I've tried:

```
items.map(res => ({
  ...res.Users,
  Users: items
    .filter(id => id.Id == id.BossId)
    .map(({ Id, ...rest }) => rest)
  }))
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your component n the question.

Comment: @AndrewL that is the only component I'm working with, you'll find whole component on Sandbox link

Comment: Code in external links are not allowed here. Please post the whole component in the question itself.

Comment: @AndrewL Yes I am aware of that but I thought I would be a good idea to include a sandbox. I Updated the question.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag... This is not about JSON.

Comment: Sure @trincot ,will do

Comment: Everywhere where you wrote "JSON", you should just take the word out. This is about JavaScript objects, not about JSON.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a list of subordinates by `BossId` or are you asking how to create a React component that will produce the output you included?

Comment: @ic3b3rg Yes I'm asking to get a list and sub-list of subordinates by BossId.

Comment: I'll update the question with specifics

Comment: Please update your question to a basic `input`, `expected output`, and what you've tried

Comment: @ic3b3rg I have already include what I have tried so far in the question, input parameters and expected output.

Comment: 1. The React code is not relevant to your question 2. The expected output of a function that retrieves subordinates by `BossId` for an example using the input you've provided and a `BossId` of `'03'` would produce a list of two employees, not this entire nested output you've shown

Comment: @ic3b3rg Sorry for the irrelevant title or misleading question, and can you please demonstrate with a working example of how or what approach should I do in order to get the expected output?

Comment: I've edited your question down to what I think you're asking - is that accurate?

Comment: @ic3b3rg Yes, that is accurate, but you seem to remove the expected output.

Comment: I do have an expected output - if you want the full nested output you posted earlier, then I suggest you update the question with the output you expect using JS data models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go a step further and create a generic filter function for any property (or combination thereof) like this:

```js
function filterItemsBy (items, filter = {}) {
  const filterBy = Object.entries(filter).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => item => item[key] === value && acc(item),
    () => true
  )

  return items.filter(filterBy)
}

// usage
const items = [{BossId:'03',DateOfBirth:'1966-09-27T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Montejano',Gender:'Unspecified',GivenName:'Trinh',Id:'08',Title:'Tech Manager'},{BossId:'00',DateOfBirth:'1927-01-29T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Fetzer',Gender:'Unspecified',GivenName:'Winfred',Id:'00',Title:'CEO'},{BossId:'01',DateOfBirth:'1927-08-20T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Dandrea',Gender:'Male',GivenName:'Erich',Id:'02',Title:'VP of Marketing'},{BossId:'01',DateOfBirth:'1929-02-07T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Nisbet',Gender:'Male',GivenName:'Reinaldo',Id:'03',Title:'VP of Technology'},{BossId:'01',DateOfBirth:'1932-06-13T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Bufford',Gender:'Unspecified',GivenName:'Alleen',Id:'04',Title:'VP of HR'},{BossId:'02',DateOfBirth:'1936-09-26T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Klopfer',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Kristyn',Id:'05',Title:'Director of Marketing'},{BossId:'01',DateOfBirth:'1937-11-23T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Duhon',Gender:'Male',GivenName:'Sophie',Id:'01',Title:'Tech Manager'},{BossId:'03',DateOfBirth:'1948-04-05T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Mirabal',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Suanne',Id:'07',Title:'Tech Manager'},{BossId:'04',DateOfBirth:'1966-10-13T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Maslowski',Gender:'Unspecified',GivenName:'Norah',Id:'09',Title:'Tech Manager'},{BossId:'06',DateOfBirth:'1967-08-25T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Redford',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Gertrudis',Id:'10',Title:'Tech Lead'},{BossId:'06',DateOfBirth:'1968-12-26T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Tobey',Gender:'Male',GivenName:'Donovan',Id:'11',Title:'Tech Lead'},{BossId:'09',DateOfBirth:'1969-10-16T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Vermeulen',Gender:'Male',GivenName:'Rich',Id:'12',Title:'Trainer Lead'},{BossId:'09',DateOfBirth:'1972-10-16T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Knupp',Gender:'Male',GivenName:'Santo',Id:'13',Title:'HR Manager'},{BossId:'12',DateOfBirth:'1974-03-23T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Grooms',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Jazmin',Id:'14',Title:'Trainer'},{BossId:'13',DateOfBirth:'1978-08-25T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Cheeks',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Annelle',Id:'15',Title:'Recruiter'},{BossId:'15',DateOfBirth:'1979-08-21T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Harshaw',Gender:'Unspecified',GivenName:'Eliza',Id:'16',Title:'Trainer'},{BossId:'08',DateOfBirth:'1980-02-09T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Broaddus',Gender:'Unspecified',GivenName:'Xiomara',Id:'17',Title:'Senior Software Developer'},{BossId:'11',DateOfBirth:'1981-09-08T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Jungers',Gender:'Unspecified',GivenName:'Erminia',Id:'18',Title:'Software Developer'},{BossId:'10',DateOfBirth:'1984-03-18T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Moffatt',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Maria',Id:'19',Title:'Software Developer'},{BossId:'10',DateOfBirth:'1990-09-24T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Grimaldo',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Tammera',Id:'20',Title:'Senior Software Developer'},{BossId:'10',DateOfBirth:'1992-06-18T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Das',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Sharyl',Id:'21',Title:'Software Developer'},{BossId:'08',DateOfBirth:'1993-11-15T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Harlan',Gender:'Unspecified',GivenName:'Shan',Id:'22',Title:'UI Developer'},{BossId:'11',DateOfBirth:'1997-03-23T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Almeida',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Mariah',Id:'23',Title:'QA Tester'},{BossId:'11',DateOfBirth:'1998-11-10T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Kerfien',Gender:'Male',GivenName:'Darnell',Id:'24',Title:'QA Tester'},{BossId:'11',DateOfBirth:'2004-04-22T00:00:00',FamilyName:'Vierra',Gender:'Female',GivenName:'Janell',Id:'25',Title:'QA Tester'}]

console.log(filterItemsBy(items, { BossId: '03' }))
```

Comment: This is a very readable function by far and flexible as well, but by generic, doesn't it means it has drawbacks?

Comment: If I had to list any drawbacks, I'd say that it requires the caller to specify an object with key-pair entries instead of a single value where the key is hard-coded in the implementation. But even that "drawback" allows the caller to be self-documenting, so it's hardly a drawback at all. You can even call it with `filterItemsBy(items, { BossId: '03', Gender: 'Female' })` and it will list only the one matching entry in your example data without having to rewrite the implementation for each property.

Comment: It took me time to understand the function, and I did before your comment, thank you for your insight. As I pointed out before this function is very flexible in ways to use.

Comment: What if `items` is not a variable but stored in an external JSON file?

Comment: @YashKaranke loading data from external files is a separate concern. Don't mix your concerns; load the data then filter it once it's available in memory. The scope of this question and answer only addresses the concern of filtering data.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `filter` instead of `map`. Map always creates an array of the same length as the original, while filtering will produce a subset:

```
function getItemsByBossId (items, id) {
  return items.filter(item => item.BossId === id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter (as mentioned by djfdev) or create a function by yourself like this

```
 function provideID (mainItem, id) {
    let arrayData = [] //We will push data to this array 
    for (let i=0; i<mainItem.length; i++) {
        if (Number(mainItem[i]["BossId"]) === id) arrayData.push(mainItem[i])
    }
    return arrayData;
  }

  console.log(provideID(items, 10))
```

here **mainItem is your data array object and Id is the BossID corresponding to which you need to have data**

Just keep in mind that you are **most likely** going to **pass integer** and your **BossID is a string** so you need to **convert one of them**.

Above, I have converted BossID to number. if you don't need that, you can just do

```
if (mainItem[i]["BossId"] === id) arrayData.push(mainItem[i])
```

Comment: your variable name `mainItems` is wrong inside function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing it out. Previously wrote a function which just takes in ID thinking items is in global scope but later saw another answer where answerer passed the array object as well.