# Local JSON Schema returns empty

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a local JSON schema which I filter through and display it by certain `Id`. The following is JSON Schema.

`Users.json`

```
[
  {
    "BossId": "03",
    "DateOfBirth": "1966-09-27T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Montejano",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Trinh",
    "Id": "08",
    "Title": "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "00",
    "DateOfBirth": "1927-01-29T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Fetzer",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Winfred",
    "Id": "00",
    "Title": "CEO"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "01",
    "DateOfBirth": "1927-08-20T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Dandrea",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "GivenName": "Erich",
    "Id": "02",
    "Title": "VP of Marketing"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "01",
    "DateOfBirth": "1929-02-07T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Nisbet",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "GivenName": "Reinaldo",
    "Id": "03",
    "Title": "VP of Technology"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "01",
    "DateOfBirth": "1932-06-13T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Bufford",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Alleen",
    "Id": "04",
    "Title": "VP of HR"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "02",
    "DateOfBirth": "1936-09-26T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Klopfer",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Kristyn",
    "Id": "05",
    "Title": "Director of Marketing"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "01",
    "DateOfBirth": "1937-11-23T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Duhon",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "GivenName": "Sophie",
    "Id": "01",
    "Title": "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "03",
    "DateOfBirth": "1948-04-05T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Mirabal",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Suanne",
    "Id": "07",
    "Title": "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "04",
    "DateOfBirth": "1966-10-13T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Maslowski",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Norah",
    "Id": "09",
    "Title": "Tech Manager"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "06",
    "DateOfBirth": "1967-08-25T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Redford",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Gertrudis",
    "Id": "10",
    "Title": "Tech Lead"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "06",
    "DateOfBirth": "1968-12-26T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Tobey",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "GivenName": "Donovan",
    "Id": "11",
    "Title": "Tech Lead"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "09",
    "DateOfBirth": "1969-10-16T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Vermeulen",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "GivenName": "Rich",
    "Id": "12",
    "Title": "Trainer Lead"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "09",
    "DateOfBirth": "1972-10-16T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Knupp",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "GivenName": "Santo",
    "Id": "13",
    "Title": "HR Manager"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "12",
    "DateOfBirth": "1974-03-23T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Grooms",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Jazmin",
    "Id": "14",
    "Title": "Trainer"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "13",
    "DateOfBirth": "1978-08-25T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Cheeks",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Annelle",
    "Id": "15",
    "Title": "Recruiter"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "15",
    "DateOfBirth": "1979-08-21T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Harshaw",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Eliza",
    "Id": "16",
    "Title": "Trainer"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "08",
    "DateOfBirth": "1980-02-09T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Broaddus",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Xiomara",
    "Id": "17",
    "Title": "Senior Software Developer"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "11",
    "DateOfBirth": "1981-09-08T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Jungers",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Erminia",
    "Id": "18",
    "Title": "Software Developer"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "10",
    "DateOfBirth": "1984-03-18T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Moffatt",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Maria",
    "Id": "19",
    "Title": "Software Developer"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "10",
    "DateOfBirth": "1990-09-24T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Grimaldo",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Tammera",
    "Id": "20",
    "Title": "Senior Software Developer"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "10",
    "DateOfBirth": "1992-06-18T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Das",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Sharyl",
    "Id": "21",
    "Title": "Software Developer"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "08",
    "DateOfBirth": "1993-11-15T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Harlan",
    "Gender": "Unspecified",
    "GivenName": "Shan",
    "Id": "22",
    "Title": "UI Developer"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "11",
    "DateOfBirth": "1997-03-23T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Almeida",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Mariah",
    "Id": "23",
    "Title": "QA Tester"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "11",
    "DateOfBirth": "1998-11-10T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Kerfien",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "GivenName": "Darnell",
    "Id": "24",
    "Title": "QA Tester"
  },
  {
    "BossId": "11",
    "DateOfBirth": "2004-04-22T00:00:00",
    "FamilyName": "Vierra",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "GivenName": "Janell",
    "Id": "25",
    "Title": "QA Tester"
  }
]
```

In my component, I am importing the JSON file and then a method to filter through and display the result.

So far, I've used `axios`, `fetch` and `componentDidMount` to achieve my goal. My Component.

```
import React from "react";
import items from "../data/Users";
class OrgChartList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Users: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    const params = this.props.match.params.id;
    function filterItemsBy(items, filter = {}) {
      const filterBy = Object.entries(filter).reduce(
        (acc, [key, value]) => item => item[key] === value && acc(item),
        () => true
      );
      return items.filter(filterBy);
    }
    return (
      <div>{JSON.stringify(filterItemsBy(items, { BossId: params }))}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default OrgChartList;
```

If I use JSON Object as JavaScript Object, it works perfectly like

`const items = [{}]` but while importing it return emtpy array.

Comment: Are you using Webpack? What does your `webpack.config.js` file look like?

Comment: No, I'm using `create-react-app`

Comment: I'm finding your `filterBy` reducer really confusing. What does it do?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859384/10415043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CRA, you should be able to import `json` files.  If you aren't, you'll need `json-loader`.

It looks like you are trying to filter the list of users by an `id` attached to the url.

Using CRA and your data file, I was able to filter just fine:
https://codesandbox.io/s/4ry755y1rw

I'd bet something weird is going on in your `filterItemsBy` function

Comment: Okay, how would you map so that all details of particular `Id` would display?

Comment: No, I meant by this https://codesandbox.io/s/3xmw41xwj5 , thank you for your assistance

Comment: You are comparing number to strings, so you aren't getting a match on the filter.  Change it to:

 componentDidMount() {
    const id = "11";
    const person = Users.filter(user => user.BossId === id)[0];
    console.log("PERSON", person);

    this.setState({ person });
  }